# Metacaractere retrovisor \x não pega os grupos correspondentes quando mudo a ordem destes

Tags: r, regex

O metacaractere retrovisor `\x` repete algo capturado em algum grupo `()` anterior na regex.

Por exemplo:

```
library(stringr)

a <- 'quero-quero'

str_extract(string = a, pattern = regex(pattern = '(quero)-\\1'))

[1] "quero-quero"
```

Este resultado está ok. O procedimento é relativamente simples, pois existe apenas um grupo. Os seguintes procedimentos não trazem os grupos correspondentes:

```
b <- 'lentamente é mente lenta'

str_extract(string = b, pattern = regex(pattern = '(lenta)(mente) é \\2 \\1'))

[1] "lentamente é mente lenta"
```

Isso funciona, mas quando inverto a ordem dos grupos, não me é trazido o grupo correspondente:

```
str_extract(string = b, pattern = regex(pattern = '(lenta)(mente) é \\1 \\2'))

[1] NA
```

O mesmo processo se repete para os seguintes casos:

Exemplo adicional 1:

```
c <- 'bandeirante é bandeira band'

str_extract(string = c, pattern = regex(pattern = '(((band)eira)nte) é \\2 \\3'))

[1] "bandeirante é bandeira band"

# invertendo o grupo
str_extract(string = c, pattern = regex(pattern = '(((band)eira)nte) é \\3 \\2'))

[1] NA
```

Exemplo adicional 2:

```
d <- 'indolor é sem dor'

str_extract(string = d, pattern = regex(pattern = 'in(d)ol(or) é sem \\1\\2'))

[1] "indolor é sem dor"

# invertendo o grupo

str_extract(string = d, pattern = regex(pattern = 'in(d)ol(or) é sem \\2\\1'))

[1] NA
```

Li [isso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), mas não consegui compreender o que ocorre. **Para mim**, era para os grupos serem retornados, mas em outra ordem. Mas, notei que não é algo tão trivial assim.

**Obs:** Em `R`, deve ser usada a dupla barra (`\\`), conforme consta [aqui](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando algum trecho da regex está entre parênteses, isso forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Os grupos são numerados de acordo com a ordem em que aparecem na expressão. Ou seja, nesta regex:

```
(lenta)(mente)
```

Temos dois pares de parênteses, e portanto, dois grupos de captura. O primeiro (grupo 1) é o que contém a string "lenta" e o segundo (grupo 2) contém "mente".

Os retrovisores (ou [*backreferences*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)) servem para referenciar um grupo existente, para que não tenhamos que escrever a mesma coisa de novo. Isso quer dizer que as duas regex abaixo são equivalentes:

```
(lenta)(mente) é \\2 \\1
lentamente é mente lenta
```

Tanto que o código abaixo:

```
library(stringr)

a <- 'lentamente é mente lenta'

str_extract(string = a, pattern = '(lenta)(mente) é \\2 \\1')
str_extract(string = a, pattern = 'lentamente é mente lenta')
```

Resulta em:

```
[1] "lentamente é mente lenta"
[1] "lentamente é mente lenta"
```

Ambas as expressões correspondem à mesma string (`"lentamente é mente lenta"`). Repare que `\\1` é apenas um atalho para "*pegue o que foi encontrado no primeiro grupo de captura e coloque aqui*", e `\\2` faz a mesma coisa para o segundo grupo.

---

Já a regex `(lenta)(mente) é \\1 \\2` é o mesmo que `lentamente é lenta mente`. **É uma regex diferente da primeira**, por isso ela não encontra um *match* quando você usa faz uma busca na string `"lentamente é mente lenta"`. Tanto que o código abaixo:

```
library(stringr)

a <- c('lentamente é mente lenta', 'lentamente é lenta mente')

str_extract(string = a, pattern = '(lenta)(mente) é \\1 \\2')
```

Retorna o seguinte:

```
[1] NA                         "lentamente é lenta mente"
```

---

Nos seu exemplos talvez não fique tão claro a utilidade disso, mas imagine o exemplo abaixo:

```
library(stringr)

b <- c('ab', 'cc')

str_extract(string = b, pattern = '([a-z])\\1')
```

A regex busca por uma letra de `a` a `z` (`[a-z]`) seguida da mesma letra. Ou seja, ela busca por duas letras seguidas que sejam iguais. O resultado é:

```
[1] NA   "cc"
```

Repare que isso é diferente de `[a-z][a-z]`: esta regex pega duas letras, e ambas podem ser quaisquer letras de `a` a `z` (elas não precisam ser necessariamente a mesma letra). Se eu quiser pegar duas letras seguidas que sejam iguais, não dá para usar isso. O problema é que não tem como eu saber antes qual será a letra que está repetida (claro que eu poderia fazer `aa|bb|cc|dd...`, mas não seria nada prático, nem inteligente). Somente usando a *backreference* `\1` eu garanto que a segunda letra é a mesma que foi capturada pelos parênteses. É uma forma esperta de referenciar um trecho que já foi encontrado antes.

---

Dito isso, colocar os grupos fora de ordem (como em `(lenta)(mente) é \\2 \\1`) **não** faz os grupos serem invertidos na string original. Ao buscar um *match*, você está verificando se a string corresponde à expressão - e no caso, a expressão diz que você tem uma string com trechos que se repetem em determinada ordem. Mas a busca por um *match*, por si só, não modifica a string original.

Se quer modificar algo na string, você deve fazer substituições, como já indicado na [resposta do Rui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/415824/112052). Ex:

```
b <- 'lentamente'

sub('(lenta)(mente)', '\\1\\2 é \\2 \\1', b)
```

O primeiro parâmetro é a regex `(lenta)(mente)`, que possui dois grupos de captura (o primeiro é "lenta" e o segundo é "mente"). No segundo parâmetro eu indico qual será a substituição feita, e repare que eu uso as *backreferences* mais de uma vez.

No caso, a string de substituição diz o seguinte:

- coloque o primeiro grupo de captura (`\\1`), e depois o segundo (`\\2`)
- coloque espaço, a letra `é` e outro espaço
- coloque o segundo grupo de captura, um espaço e o primeiro grupo de captura

O resultado é:

```
[1] "lentamente é mente lenta"
```

Answer (score 3):

Vou simplificar um pouco o código, uma vez que não são necessárias chamadas a `regex`, o seguinte é, no caso da pergunta, equivalente.

```
library(stringr)

b <- 'lentamente é mente lenta'

str_extract(string = b, pattern = '(lenta)(mente) é \\2 \\1')
str_extract(string = b, pattern = '(lenta)(mente) é \\1 \\2')
```

O que está a acontecer é que

1. No primeiro caso, o padrão `'(lenta)(mente) é \\2 \\1'` pode ser encontrado em `b` e portanto `str_extract` consegue extraí-lo. Não há qualquer problema.
2. No segundo caso, o padrão `'(lenta)(mente) é \\1 \\2'` não ocorre em `b`. Este padrão expande para `'(lenta)(mente) é lenta mente'`, os metacaracteres `\1` e `\2` são corretamente substituídos pelas strings capturadas anteriormente. Como a totalidade da regex não é encontrada, o resultado é `NA`.

Veja agora com `sub`, que o R está a processar os retrovisores bem.

```
sub('(lenta)(mente)', '\\2 \\1', b)
#[1] "mente lenta é mente lenta"

sub('(lenta)(mente)', '\\1 \\2', b)
#[1] "lenta mente é mente lenta"
```

Os resultados dos outros exemplos da pergunta são análogos.